# Algorithm to post-process (clustering) object tracking results

Tags: python, deep-learning, cluster-analysis, object-detection

The idea is to detect and track the cars in the video and estimate their distance. The image bellow is the estimated distances color coded based on the tracking ID. There are three cars in this example video (red color trajectory, purple trajectory, and the third trajectory which starts with blue and ended with pink color).

**Question:**

As you see in the third trajectory, track IDs changes (the color changes), but they are all related to one car. I want to do some sort of post processing to cluster my data. Do you know any algorithm which is suitable for this use case? Any hint is appreciated. (DBSCAN does not improve the results! :-( )

[image]